# Pass in keystore password of carbon server when running ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure NOT when prompted

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am trying to run the `ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure` command to encrypt the passwords in my WSO2 Identity Server.

I have gone through the usual process of running the command, then entering the keystore password when prompted.  Ex:

```
>./ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 20 seconds
Using CARBON_HOME:   C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.7.0
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
[Please Enter Primary KeyStore Password of Carbon Server : ]
```

I want to make the process more automated and include the keystore password of the Carbon Server when running the `ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure` command, NOT when the prompt is shown.

I know that you can leverage the `password-tmp` file when DECRYPTING passwords as described here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Resolving+Encrypted+Passwords

This lets you skip the step where the password is prompted.  Can we do something similar when ENCRYPTING passwords?

Things I have tried:

1. The "yes" command: `yes PASSWORD| $WSO2IS_HOME/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure`
2. Using "echo": `echo PASSWORD | $WSO2IS_HOME/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure`
3. Redirecting from a file: `$WSO2IS_HOME/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure < PASSWORD.txt`

Every time I run these command, the ciphertool script doesn't seem to pick up on the password I am trying to pass in.  The error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.wso2.ciphertool.exception.CipherToolException: String cannot be null
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.getValueFromConsole(Utils.java:54)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.KeyStoreUtil.initializeCipher(KeyStoreUtil.java:48)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.main(CipherTool.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out WSO2 IS supports this.  I wasn't able to find it documented anywhere though.

The `initialize()` method in CipherTool.java (https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool/blob/master/components/ciphertool/src/main/java/org/wso2/ciphertool/CipherTool.java) has this code

```
private static void initialize(String[] args) {
    String property;
    for (String arg : args) {
        if (arg.equals("-help")) {
            printHelp();
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (arg.substring(0, 2).equals("-D")) {
            property = arg.substring(2);
            if (property.equals(Constants.CONFIGURE)) {
                System.setProperty(property, Constants.TRUE);
            } else if (property.equals(Constants.CHANGE)) {
                System.setProperty(property, Constants.TRUE);
            } else if (property.length() >= 8 && property.substring(0, 8).equals(Constants.CONSOLE_PASSWORD_PARAM)) {
                System.setProperty(Constants.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, property.substring(9));
            } else {
                System.out.println("This option is not define!");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    Utils.setSystemProperties();
}
```

`Constants.CONSOLE_PASSWORD_PARAM` is "password".

So the command to pass in the keystore password would look like this:

`>./ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure -Dpassword=MY_PASSWORD`